# Кривое отображение элементов при прокрутке слайдера

Tags: jquery, slider, плагин

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите в решении проблемы! Имеется [слайдер](http://lelbrus.by/) типа "карусель" на основе [данного плагина](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/), суть проблемы заключается в том, что когда происходит прокрутка слайдера таблица с картинками и подписями к ним не изменяет свой размер вместе с фоновой картинкой, а также при прокручивании слайдера эта таблица съезжает, как закрепить эту таблицу и уменьшать ее при прокручивании, также еще название блока съезжает при прокручивании.

Заранее очень буду благодарен за проявленную помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте внутри элемента списка `div` с `background: url('images/blockONE.png')`, а внутри этого блока уже размещайте вашу таблицу. Тогда всё нормально будет отображаться.

Второй вариант: не меняя структуры, редактируем немного стили, которые у вас уже есть таким образом (добавляем или исправляем для элементов внутри li):

1. `li {overflow: hidden}`
2. `span {position: absolute}`
3. `img {position: absolute}`
4. `table {position: absolute; display: block;}`

`top` и `left/right`-свойства для элементов потом по вкусу. Но вообще я бы поискал более лучший вариант: или только картинку внутри или другой плагин.

Comment: Спасибо, Роман! Да, действительно помогло, единственное, что осталось так это то, что при масштабировании этого DIV его фон не меняет размер, т.е. плагин уменьшает размер элемента, а фон остается с теми размерами, что у подложенной картинки, получается обрезанный фон, хотя я даже размеры не указывал для фоновой картинки! Может у вас есть еще что-то на этот счет?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Роман, а какой другой плагин посоветуете? Я уже все наверное перерыл в гугле по ключевым словам "слайдер карусель"!

Comment: И что, ничего не понравилось?

Comment: Просто ничего такого нету, чтобы подходило под мои задачи...